# How to add a Facebook share button for my embed YouTube playlist

Tags: javascript, facebook, youtube

```
<div id=player></div>
<div id=share style="width:100px; height:50px; background-color:#c33333"></div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '448',
          width: '763',
          playerVars: {
              'showinfo': 0,
              'controls': 0,
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: 'PLD7SqVUGDdDBw_xmMKTDF5MlBwys_KlUk'
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        // event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function play_this_video(){
 player.playVideo();
}


      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          player.stopVideo();
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Hi, I'm a newbie about JavaScript so I can't figure out how to make that. I have an embedded code like shown above, and I want that div named "share" act as a Facebook share button, but the main problem is I want it to share last played or active video from the embedded playlist.

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building your own div for share button:

```
<div id=share style="width:100px; height:50px; background-color:#c33333"></div>
```

You will need to use the facebook share button from the facebook page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

When you click on `Get Code` it will generate the code in which there will be a URL in the HTML

**SOLUTION # 1**

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com.com&amp;layout=button_count&amp;appId=688937844491820" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**SOLUTION # 2**

Replace your share button with following HTML

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Put the following right after `<body>` tag

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=688937844491820&version=v2.0";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Replace the `www.example.com` with your video or playlist URL

Comment: Hey thank you, but I need to build my own one. And the previous answer was fine for me to handle it. But you changed it, can you please add them again?

Thanks again:)

Comment: np, i have added it back you can use solution 2 for your custom button.

Comment: it still generates the classic facebook share button on my div which I want to make it a button. @Qambar